# Conditional database connection string .NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am  developing an application that uses entity framework, the database connection string is stored in web.config.

What I want to do is when I running locally I want to use a local database but when I check-in the code in TFS Service and it is deployed I want the application to use another connection string.

any help how this can be accomplished.

Comment: [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Project Deployment Using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) would be the obvious route. It even has "The following example shows the contents of a transform file that changes a connection string ..."

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with Web.config Transorm

Have a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx